# How to Maven JUnit-test HTML pages containing Javascript and calling a servlet?

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, maven, junit

I am still new to Javascript and Servlets. I have some HTML pages containing javascript code and these pages can call a servlet. I want to develop JUnit-like test for this page to run from Maven.

I googled and found [JSUnit](http://www.jsunit.net/) to test Javascript and [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/servletunit-intro.html) to test Servlets, but how can I test my HTML page by simulating clicks and user actions? Is there a framework to write these tests in a Java/JUnit fashion? Basically, I want to automate these as part of a maven compilation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a combination of [JWebUnit](http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/) as the driver and [easyb](http://www.easyb.org/) for writing specifications.

JWebUnit will drive either [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). This is both good and bad; good because the behavioral tests can run on a headless server via HtmlUnit, bad because I lose some functionality of HtmlUnit in the process... some tests "go native". Pretty good JavaScript support, too.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Selenium and Watir?  Selenium can capture the clicks and then be put into a jUnit framework to run like it was unit tests.  Watir does the same type of thing in Ruby.